# How to draw image on 3d canvas using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have this

```
function doFirst(){
    var x = document.getElementById('canvas'); 
    var canvas = x.getContext('webgl') || x.getContext("experimental-webgl");
 }
```

And I want to draw a image 'sheep.png' on the canvas. I use this but it is not working:

```
var pic = new Image();
pic.src = "images/sheep.png";
pic.addEventListener("load", function() { canvas.drawImage(pic,0,0,0)}, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

`drawImage` is only for use with the 2D context, you can't use it in a webgl context.

In order to use it in webgl, you'll need to build a mesh with your image used as the texture.

If you're not familiar with webgl, you might want to look at three.js as an alternative that's easier to use.

Answer (score -1):

```
drawImage()
```

takes only 3 arguments I guess.

See this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h36Xq/).

and this [reference](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-images/)